# Develop branch is behind after merging into master using Gitlab MR

Tags: git, gitlab

I have merged some changes from develop into master using GitLab merge request and I squashed the commits. After merging, I compared the two branches and it shows the wrong diffs. I expected no diffs since they are the same after merging. I checked the commit graph and I see that the develop and master branch are now disconnected.

Graph after merge:
[image]

Why is the master branch ahead of the develop after merge? Is this expected behavior? I am using  Gitlab 12.9. I want to retain the develop branch for future development but I want to avoid unnecessary diffs to show up.

Comment: That's expected. Squashing commits makes a new commit.

Comment: Hello @DanielMann. So do you suggest not squashing? I want to keep my develop branch for future development but I don't want the unexpected diffs to appear.

Comment: If the only branch you merge to master is develop, you could a rebase/fast-forward nerges in that case without problems. (If you want all commits to be copied)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially, git only has one way of tracking history: every commit has zero or more parents. By tracking backwards from a commit to its parents, and their parents, git can determine what commits are in that commit's history.

When you merge two branches, say develop into master, you have three choices:

1. If all the commits on master already exist on develop, you can just move the branch pointer of master to match develop, without creating any new commits. This is a "fast-forward merge".
2. You can create a new commit which has both develop and master as its parents. All the commits that are in develop's history are now in master's history as well.
3. You can "squash" all the differences between the two branches into one commit, with only master as its parent. All the *changes* from develop will now be on master, but none of the *commits* that made up those changes are in master's history.

When you next ask to merge the same branches, git will look for commits which exist on develop but don't exist on master. If you took option 3, *all those commits you squashed the changes from are still in that category*.

The lesson is to only use squash merges on branches you're going to throw away afterwards. For instance, each task you work on can be in a new branch; you start it from the current state of develop (or master, or main, or wherever), squash merge it, and then delete the branch. The next task starts again from develop/master/main, not from the old task branch, so the old commits that you squashed away don't matter any more.

Alternatively (and my personal preference), don't use squash merges. Make each commit meaningful, use `git rebase -i` and `git commit --amend` to tidy up stupid mistakes you don't want in your history (being careful to only rewrite history that you haven't shared with other users, or other branches), and then use a fast-forward merge or a merge commit.

Comment: I would add to "The lesson is ..." that in addition to using squash merges on throw-away branches, presumably those to be deleted, that it could also be done for branches you want to retain but not re-use.

Comment: @MCornejo I'd still count that as "throwaway" - you can't do anything meaningful with that branch, because it doesn't relate to your other branches in any way. I guess you could manually work out which it was, and go back and look at the commits, but if you think you might want that information, just use a true merge in the first place.